# SSH connection to Gitlab is getting timeout

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, gitlab

I've followed the official Gitlab docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/) to make my keys using the comand:

```
 ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com"
```

But I'm getting timeout error as you can see at this image:
[All my issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EHHJ.png)

The first page is the error, the pane below at left is the content of my `~/.ssh/config` file, and the last pane is the content of my `~/.ssh` directory.

**Edit1:**

I've tried to connect with telnet with the command `telnet gitlab.com 22` and I'm getting `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`.

But I can ping gitlab normally

[image: Ping to Gitlab]

**Edit2:**

I've got it. I have to change my `~/.ssh/config` and put these lines:

```
Host gitlab.com
  Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
  User git
  Port 443
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I've followed this tutorial: [here](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/)

Comment: This sounds like a (possibly transient) network problem and not an ssh / authentication problem.  What happens if you type `telnet gitlab.com 22`?  If it clears the screen and gives you some kind of banner, hit Enter to get back to your shell prompt and try the `ssh` again.  If the `telnet` fails, then you simply have a problem connecting to gitlab.com.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: gitlab.com is not listening on port 22, I've tested it from France, UK and USA

Comment: And how can I workaround of it?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. I have to change my ~/.ssh/config and put these lines:

```
Host gitlab.com
  Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
  User git
  Port 443
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I've followed this tutorial: [here](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/)

Comment: care to explain why this is necessary?